# Xamarin.Forms ListView SeprartorVisibility property not found

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin.Forms. In listview, the separatorvisibility property is missing. Version 1.3.5.6335.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to I think it was 1.5.0 at least. But if you upgrade to 2.0.1 (the current latest) it will certainly be there.

Answer (score 0):

`SeparatorVisibility` was introduced in 1.4.0.6341.

You will need to upgrade your project to a later version to access this.

The documentation is slightly out of date.